# How to create an array, a textfield will receive data, divided by comma, all the elements in this textfield will be elements in array

Tags: arrays, swift

I got a question when I deal with the array in SWIFT. What I can do if I want to create a textfield and receive data, and each of the element in the text field divided by comma. I want to create an array, and all of the elements in the textfield are the elements in this array and in fixed sequence.

What I can do now, is receive date from textfield and can only make the information in the textfield as one element in the array. Can any one help me to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want every symbol from textfield to be a separate element of array use for...in like this:

```
var s = someTextField.text
var someArray: [String] = []

for i in s {
   someArray.append(String(i))
}
```

And if elements in textField separated by comma you can use this code to get them into your array:

```
var s=someTextField.text.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

for var i=0; i<s.count; i++ {
   someArray.append(s[i])
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I want, thx